# Writing a simple benchmark to test scala twirl tempaltes is giving a runtime error

Tags: scala, jmh

I'm trying this scala microbenchmark plugin, sbt-jmh,  and I am getting an error.

```
package play.twirl.benchmarks

import play.twirl.parser._
import play.twirl.parser.TreeNodes._
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Benchmark

class TwirlBenchmark {

  @Benchmark
  def simpleParse(): Template = {
    val parser = new TwirlParser(false)
    val template = "<h1>hello</h1>@someVar"    
    parser.parse(template) match {
      case parser.Success(tmpl, input) =>
        if (!input.atEnd) sys.error("Template parsed but not at source end")
        tmpl
      case parser.Error(_, _, errors) =>
        sys.error("Template failed to parse: " + errors.head.str)
    }
  }

}
```

It compiles fine, but when running the benchmark:

jmh:run

I get these errors:

```
[info] # Warmup Iteration   1: <failure>
[info] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/util/parsing/input/Position
[info]  at play.twirl.benchmarks.TwirlBenchmark.simpleParse(TwirlBenchmarks.scala:23)
[info]  at play.twirl.benchmarks.generated.TwirlBenchmark_simpleParse_jmhTest.simpleParse_thrpt_jmhStub(TwirlBenchmark_simpleParse_jmhTest.java:119)
[info]  at play.twirl.benchmarks.generated.TwirlBenchmark_simpleParse_jmhTest.simpleParse_Throughput(TwirlBenchmark_simpleParse_jmhTest.java:83)
[info]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[info]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[info]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[info]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[info]  at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:453)
[info]  at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.BenchmarkHandler$BenchmarkTask.call(BenchmarkHandler.java:437)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[info]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[info]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[info] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.util.parsing.input.Position
[info]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[info]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[info]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
[info]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[info]  ... 15 more
[info] # Run complete. Total time: 00:00:02
```

Not sure how to proceed.  Help?

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators

Be sure to include the appropriate version based on Scala version and Play version

Comment: but it compiles?